# Join two tables, only display unique values and maxium date

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I am trying to join two tables, but only display the unique rows and the latest date.

Looking online I have discovered various ways to achieve or the joining of two tables, or the selection of unique rows (and latest date) in a single table. How would I go about combining these two?

Joining two tables:

```
select * 
from Table01 AS s
left join Table02 AS p on s.id = p.id
```

Get unique rows, and latest date - in a single table:

```
select * from (
    select id_01, id_02, max(dt_date) AS MaxDt 
    from Table01 
    group by id_01, id_02) TempTable
join Table01 ComTable on
    TempTable.id_01 = ComTable.id_01 and
    TempTable.id_02 = ComTable.id_02 and
    TempTable.MaxDt = ComTable.dt_date
order by ComTable.dt_date desc;
```

I think I know how to do it theoretically (`Table01` in the second query should be the result of the first query, or get the latest date row before joiing the two tables) but have no clue how to apply it in practice.

**EDIT:**
What I am trying to do:
Join two tables, selecting all columns (columns with ambiguous names will not  be included or assigned a unique alias). On this freshly created joined table I would like to display all unique rows (based on an id) with the latest date. (or alternatively select the latest unique row and than join two tables).

Example data:

```
Table01
ID  column01    column02    column0X
10  test        test123     testABC

Table02
ID  columnA     columnB     columnY     dt_date
10  data01      data02      data03      01/01/2012
10  data11      data12      data13      02/02/2012
10  data21      data22      data23      03/03/2012
10  data31      data32      data33      04/04/2012

Joined Table
ID  column01    column02    column0X    columnA     columnB     columnY     dt_date
10  test        test123     testABC     data01      data02      data03      01/01/2012
10  test        test123     testABC     data11      data12      data13      02/02/2012
10  test        test123     testABC     data21      data22      data23      03/03/2012
10  test        test123     testABC     data31      data32      data33      04/04/2012

Actual Output
ID  column01    column02    column0X    columnA     columnB     columnY     dt_date
10  test        test123     testABC     data31      data32      data33      04/04/2012
```

On the issue regarding the linked solution:
Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338332/joining-two-mssql-tables-unique-values) results in the following error:
`The column 'xyz' was specified multiple times for 'Table01'.`

Removing all duplicate columns (or using unique aliases), result in the following error:
`Column 'xyz' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

(Where "xyz" could be a number of different columns.)

```
SELECT 
  p.*, d.*
FROM Table01 p
left join
(  SELECT 
    alotofcolumnshere,MAX(dt_date) MaxDate
   FROM Table02 s 
   GROUP BY s.id
) d  ON p.id = d.id
     ORDER BY d.maxdate DESC;
```

Please note this error is persistent until I remove all columns in the select statement except for column `id` and `MaxDate`. Which seems to make sense as I cannot group on any of the other columns. Also the previous query (and the corresponding question) solely try to find the maximum date and add it to the equivalent rows in another table. Therefore I was asking for another method, as I don't think this will work on the data set.

Thank you,

Comment: The column 'xyz' was specified multiple times for 'Table' - use google for this. Anyway, it means that two columns have the same name in the list of tables which you are joining. If you need that, then use aliases.

Comment: were you using `SELECT *` when you got the error at the bottom?  Try listing out the fields you want.

Comment: why don't you simply put your query and expected output here and make it easy for us ?

Comment: The error probably comes from the subquery (select * being the most likely cause, as Daniel E. said). However, you don't have anything aliased as 'Table' here, so could you pls show us the real statement that errors out?

Comment: Thank you, I should have been a little bit more clear. Please view the updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join the data you need to get your "Joined Table" above. You can then filter out those rows you no longer want with the additional sub select with the MAXDate. The join for this back onto the "Joined Table" needs to be by ID and Date to ensure you get only the data you want! Hope this helps :

```
SELECT p.*, p1.*
FROM Table01 p
INNER JOIN Table02 p1 ON p.Id = p1.Id
INNER JOIN
    (  SELECT s.id, MAX(dt_date) MaxDate
       FROM Table02 s 
       GROUP BY s.id
    ) d  
ON p1.id = d.id AND p1.MaxDate = d.MaxDate
ORDER BY d.maxdate DESC;
```